# Python for Loop for summation with function

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, curve-fitting, curve

I want to fit an x^n-t curve to some points.

I have an array `x=np.array([-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5])`. I have my `a=np.array([a_1,a_2,...,a_n])` so that`a.shape=n`. And what i want to do is fit a curve for the x points such:

a[0]+a[1]*x+a[2]*x^2+...+a[n]*x^n

So i want to do, lets say if n=2 `plt.plot(x,a[0]+a[1]*x+a[2]*x**2)`

Is there a way to do this?

I tried doing

```
for i in range(n):
    z=a[i]*x**i
plt.plot(x,z)
```

But this doesnt give me back what i want to plot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to plot the curve, you must solve the polynomial equation using the coefficient for every point on `x` and add it to a list. This way you can plot it against `x`. You can do this as follows:

```python
import numpy as np
x = np.array([-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5])
a = np.array([1, 2, 3]) # for example
z = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    z.append(a[0] + a[1] * x[i]**i + a[2] * x[i]**(i+1))

plt.plot(x,z)
```

Here, the loop is run in `range(len(x))` and using the coefficients, you can solve the polynomial and add it to `z` for each point of `x`.

Comment: Please do not use a loop with `append` but Numpy vectorized calls instead. This is much much more efficient for big array. Something like: `z = a[0] + a[1] * np.power(x, np.arange(len(x)) + a[2] * np.power(x, np.arange(1, len(x)+1))`